# Acessing user identity in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I want to use a lambda function that is only available to members of a Cognito user group. Within that function I want access the identity of the specific user that just called the function. So far, I did not get this to work.

I have created a Cognito group and have prepared an HTML-page with JS that can register, confirm and login users. Among other things, I can extract the identity token.

I also created an API in the API Gateway that is connected to a Lambda function. Setting the Authorization to the Cognito group works great and the function can only be called with a valid identity token.

However, I don't know how and if I can access the identity in the Lambda function this way. The flag "Invoke with caller credentials" can only be set with the Authorization AWS_IAM. This, in turn, requires a different Authorization in the HTTP request, but I don't know what I need to do there. Or am I moving into a completely wrong direction?

In other threads, e.g., https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=231032, and the documentation I found remarks about setting up a request mapping template, but I found no location in the GUI where I could do anything like that.

I'd appreciate any help on this! If any more information can help, just ask for it and I will provide as much as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got the identity of the caller via Mapping Templates.

To use Mapping Templates via JSON format, you need to add a template "application/json". You can then click on the new entry and provide a specific template. In my case, I used

```
{
    "name": "$context.authorizer.claims.name",
    "username": "$context.authorizer.claims['cognito:username']"
}
```

This adds the attributes name and username to the event object in the lambda call, which contain the content of the attribute name and the cognito username respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Request mapping templates can be found in the GUI under Method -> Integration Response -> Mapping Templates.

A template like:

```
{"testHeader" : "$input.params().header.get('Authorization')"}
```

will pass the token to the lambda under 'testheader'.

It may also be worth checking out the context variable (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference) to see if it holds the information you require, although I don't believe it will, unless you move to a Custom Authorizer method of authentication.

Comment: How can I set that template? I find the expansion panel "Mapping Templates", but when I enter your suggested template in the Content-Type table, I get an error:  Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid content type specified: {"testHeader" : "$input.params().header.get('Authorization')"}]

The expansion panel can be found in Integration Request, not Integration Response, like you responded. Under Mapping templates, I have a selection "Request body passthrough" and a table Content-type where I can add new entries via button "Add mapping template"